# View as Web Version and how does "view_email_url" work

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

By adding "%%view_email_url%%" to your send email, an HTML anchor like this will be the outcome. 
"http://view.email.domain/?qs=cf22e6eerr5211b8dafd70d354b041e258b41d7d1284caa9c163ce40887d47847241d3a4b62385c99ff66df99d054eefffced00"

How long is this URL valid? What sources are getting accessed? What are the scenarios that will stop the URL from working?

I could not find any documentation on this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'view_email_url' will be unique for individual records in the DE you've sent from. If you remove the record from the DE it will cause the 'view_email_url' to stop working. If you have a DE which is cleared after every send (Birthday DE), you can use send logging and a bit of AMPscript at the top of the message to decide where to pull data from depending on the context - SEND, VAWP, FORWARD etc.

I don't know if the link will eventually expire but if you use the send logging method then DataView data is cleared out after 6 months. Which is more than enough time.